# の - questioning and confirmation

Tags: grammar, questions, tag-question

I learned the grammatical structure of の for questioning (and explaining) things a while ago, but the exact meaning and which gender uses it has kind of confused me.

Here are a few varied sentence I'd first like to confirm whether my understanding of the meaning is correct (I've translated them based on the feeling I'm get when I hear them):

`暇があるの？` - You have free time? (I thought you didn't)

`暇がないの？` - You don't have free time? (I thought you did)

`暇があるんじゃない？` - (But surely) You have free time don't you? (Confirming as if you know they don't) - do I need a の at the end?

`暇がないんじゃない？` - (But surely) You don't have free time don't you? (Confirming as if you know they do) - do I need a の at the end?

Isn't `暇があるんじゃないの？` not used because it doesn't make sense / sounds weird? And then should you add `か` to the end because it sounds a little feminine or replace `の` with `んですか？` or `のですか？` to be more formal?

Answer (score 2):

Explanatory の is gender-neutral. You can say 暇があるんじゃないの safely in informal settings, regardless of your sex, when you highly suspect the listener has some spare time.

As your textbook probably explains, の is used to seek clarification. You usually need some context before making a の-ending question.

- 暇(が)ある？
  Do you have time?
- 暇(が)あるの？
  (That makes me wonder, so) do you have time?